# Jinja2 multiple variables in same for loop

Tags: for-loop, jinja2

I would like to populate the same section of a Jinja2 for loop with data from 2 separate SQL queries using Python / Webapp2 / Jinja2.

Specifically, I am storing team info in a variable called "team" and score info in a variable called "wins".  I need to position some data from the wins variable directly after data from the team variable but cannot figure out how to do this within a for loop.

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve:

```
{% block content %}
{% for team in team %}
        <div>{{ team[0] }} record: {{ wins[1] }}</div>
        <div>{{ team[1] }} and {{ team[2] }}</div>
        <div>{{ team[3] }}</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

What is the best way to do this? I need to get that "wins" variable called but cannot determine how. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I usually zip them up into a list of tuples in the view function.  Make sure the teams and wins are sorted correctly beforehand.

```
team_info = zip(teams, wins)
```

And then you can access the tuples as you iterate over the list in the template

```
{% block content %}
{% for team, win in team_info %}
    <div>{{ team[0] }} record: {{ wins[1] }}</div>
    <div>{{ team[1] }} and {{ team[2] }}</div>
    <div>{{ team[3] }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this worked. Concise and thorough, cheers.